# Black screen after pressing Try Kubuntu from grub menu (trying to install kubuntu using bootable usb stick)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, kubuntu

I'm using Huawei Matebook D14 with Radeon. I am having trouble installing kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. After booting from USB, I tried the following in GRUB menu:

pressing "e" on Try Kubuntu
then using the arrow keys to replace "quiet splash" with "radeon.modeset=0"
Then press the Ctrl+x key combination to start Kubuntu so I can start installation
But sadly, the screen just goes black and the computer does nothing.

Also used only "quiet splash" and only "nomodeset" later but didn't help.
The checksum seems to be fine with the ISO.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try 21.10 instead.

Comment: @ChanganAuto also tried with 21.10. same issue there!

Comment: So, first of all, update UEFI. If the problem persists check UEFI settings as you may need to change some. And lastly try the safe graphics mode.

Comment: After trying 'safe graphics' option, i had to wait for like 15-20 mins and then it says:

[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.Card State
[FAILED] Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer.

[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon

[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon

i'm using a bootable usb stick btw.

Comment: Yes, of course you're using USB. And one of the possibilities not previously considered is it being corrupt. Have you checked the ISO after downloading? How did you made it? If you used Rufus did you selected the options for UEFI/GPT? If other then have you assured you're booting in UEFI mode (as opposed to Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that trying out a new USB stick worked perfectly. The old stick has been malfunctioning lately.

Many thanks to @ChanganAuto to remind me of this possibility.